# How to change the Content and IsSelected properties of a NavigationViewItem in WinUI 3 by locating it using its x:name or tag?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3

I create some `NavigationViewItem` and set its `x:Name` and `Tag`, like：

```xml
<NavigationView x:Name="nvSample"
                SelectionChanged="nvSample_SelectionChanged"
                IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                IsSettingsVisible="False">

        <NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="NavigationViewItem_HomePage" Icon="Home" Content="Home" Tag="HomePage" IsSelected="True" />
            <NavigationViewItem x:Name="NavigationViewItem_SimpleSortPage" Icon="Sort" Content="Sort" Tag="SimpleSortPage" />

            <...........>

        </NavigationView.MenuItems>

</NavigationView>
```

I want to find the `NavigationViewItem` object by its `x:Name` or `Tag` so that I can change `Content` and `IsSelected` property by code.

I find `Type.GetType` may get a page by `x:Name`, like:

```
Type pageSelected = Type.GetType("NumberSort.Pages.SimpleSort");
RootPageFrame.Navigate(pageSelected,this);
```

So I tried to use it to get the `NavigationViewItem` object, like:

```
var NavigationItem = (NavigationViewItem)Type.GetType("NavigationViewItem_HomePage");
```

However, its doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a easy way to do that:

```cs
public static void SwitchPage (string pageName,NavigationView navigationView)
{

    var navigationViewItems = navigationView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>().ToList();

    if (navigationViewItems != null) {
        foreach (var item in navigationViewItems)
        {
            if( item.Tag.Equals(pageName))
            {
                item.IsSelected = true; break;
            }
        }
    }
    else {throw new ArgumentNullException()};
}
```

In this example, it sets `IsSelected` property of `NavigationViewItem` as `true`, which `pageName` is equal with
`Tag` property of `NavigationViewItem`.

Comment: This code also works as long as you don't need to get nested `NavigationViewItem`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension methods like these:

**NavigationViewExtensions.cs**

```cs
public static class NavigationViewExtensions
{
    // Get all NavigationViewItems from a NavigationViewItem.
    public static IEnumerable<NavigationViewItem> GetAllNavigationViewItems(this NavigationViewItem navigationViewItem)
    {
        if (navigationViewItem.MenuItems is null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (var menuItem in navigationViewItem.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
        {
            yield return menuItem;

            if (menuItem.MenuItems is null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach (NavigationViewItem subMenuItem in menuItem.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
            {
                yield return subMenuItem;
            }
        }
    }

    // Get all NavigationViewItems from a NavigationView.
    public static IEnumerable<NavigationViewItem> GetAllNavigationViewItems(this NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        foreach (NavigationViewItem menuItem in navigationView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
        {
            yield return menuItem;

            if (menuItem.MenuItems is null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach (NavigationViewItem subMenuItem in menuItem.GetAllNavigationViewItems())
            {
                yield return subMenuItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```cs
if (this.nvSample
        .GetAllNavigationViewItems()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name is "NavigationViewItem_HomePage") is NavigationViewItem navigationViewItem)
{
    // Do something here.
}
```